# How to decode go ethereum leveldb key value pair

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, leveldb

Just for test I tried to browse leveldb records of private go ethereum node and found following types of many keys and values one example key and value is below

```
Key :
```

\x48\x5c\x22\xd5\x23\x0f\x95\x0e\x84\xeb\xcc\x48\x5b\x2c\x75\xe0\xb0\x51\x4d\x1f\xcd\x19\x8b\x4e\x81\xbf\x18\x0f\x51\xec\x94\xf4\xec

```
Value : \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02
```

so the question is 1. How can I decode this key value ? and it this key and value is encrypted ? if yes how to decrypt it ?